How can the air be warmer than both the floor and the glass ceiling of an aluminum foil-lined box in the sun?
I've constructed a styrofoam box, with the insides spray-painted black, on top of which I placed five layers of borosilicate glasses, air-gapped with a bit of cork. It is diagrammed below:

The box gets very hot in the sun, with the following temperatures over time (measured with Type K thermocouples):

For most of the experiment, the air inside is about halfway between the floor and the ceiling temperatures, which is what I'd expect. The reason the air becomes hotter than Tbottom near the end is because the sun was setting at an angle that illuminated the side with Tinsideair on it more than the middle of the box.
I was curious to see what would happen with low-emissivity insides, instead, so I wrapped the innards in foil and ran the experiment again. It got less hot, but strangely enough the inside air was almost always warmer than both the bottom and the top:

My question is, how is this possible? I would expect the ground to heat up from absorbing the sunlight, and the ground to then heat the air via convection, and the glass as well. I don't see how the air could be warmer than both the ground and the ceiling.
I thought it might be reflections from the aluminum foil, so I wrapped the Tinsideair   thermocouple with a bit of foil as well, so that any reflections from the bottom would reflect off the foil again. I also made sure to insulate all the thermocouples with a bit of tape so that the electric conductivity of the foil would not affect matters.
For added reference, a picture of the black box, covered:

The box with foil-wrapped insides, uncovered:

and covered:


Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of this setup?

@RC_23: ultimately to test the theory that a colder objects' thermal radiation can't have an effect on a warmer one, turns out that it can of course ). draft of full write-up is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10KdRW80R_W0dMXF_ZRdspzeyXIXgmbBcXsD94G-clQo/edit#heading=h.yhh7nzwivkfw .

Without more data, one can only guess what is going on, but there are at least a couple of effects that could contribute to what you observe:

Tinsideair's styrofoam radiation shield creating a local hot spot if it has lower reflectivity than aluminium foil and hence heats up relative to the foil.
Thermally driven air circulation.  For example,  the right hand side of the box gets more sunlight late in the day and heats up  relative to the left hand side. This could drive a counterclockwise air flow that takes cooler air from near Tfirst down and along the bottom cooling Tbottom and Tside before getting heated up again on the right sunlit wall where Tinsideair is.

More measurements would be needed to better figure out what is happening.

I suggest adding thermocouples (and associated radiation shields) mirroring Tside, Tfirst, and especially Tinsideair to simultaneously measure the air temperatures on opposite sides of the box.

One could also try wrapping the radiation shields in foil to see if that changes anything.

It was an excellent idea to worry about the thermocouples being heated directly by light reflected by the aluminium. Did wrapping Tinsideair in foil have no effect? It might be worth trying to insert smooth foil sheets without pressing them down (which creates wrinkles or bumps), or maybe only applying foil on the sides or bottom to see what happens.  Changing things and seeing what happens is often key to debugging an experiment.



The "local hot spot" hit it on the head, I believe. I opened up the box and looked at the Tinsideair thermocouple, and the foil was not wrapped well around it, leaving gaps with black styrofoam inside. So it must have been absorbing all the sunlight reflected off the bottom! That certainly explains it in any case. Thanks for the insight!
